# C++ compiler error c4430 "c++ doesnt support default int"

Tags: c++, int, alias, typedef

Hi im trying to define an alias called USHORT.

```
// Demonstrates typedef keyword
#include <iostream>

typedef unsigned short int USHORT;  // typedef defined

main() {
    USHORT  Width = 5;
    USHORT Length;
    Length = 10;
    USHORT Area  = Width * Length;
    std::cout << "Width:" << Width << "\n";
    std::cout << "Length: "  << Length << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Area: " << Area;
}
```

I keep getting a compiler error saying:

> Error 1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
> does not support
> default-int   c:\users\naqvi-home\documents\justit\c++\w1\cp1\list0304.cpp    8   1   ConsoleApplication3

Thanks

Comment: Which line is the error on????

Comment: it says the error is on line 8, or around line 8. using visual studios 2013 express

Comment: Note: most compilers point out at the line the error message originated from, WHERE does the compiler point in your example ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your `typedef`. The problem is that you haven't given a return type for `main`:

```
int main()
{
  // ...
}
```

A function must have a return type. The `main` function must return `int`.

Comment: just added a return 0 to the end of the main, still has the same problem.

Comment: @RehanNaqvi You need to say that the return type is `int`. See the example I gave.

Comment: ok thanks mate works now. sorry im new to c++ lol btw i just was curious , is the syntax when coding in c++ with a text editor different to coding within an ide. For example i with "#include <iostream>" in a text editor would it be the same or would i have to change it to "#include <iostream.h>". Same goes for when you want to "cout", in an ide it seems i have to do "std::cout" whereas in a text editor i could just do "cout" without the pre "std::"

Comment: @RehanNaqvi The syntax for C++ is the same everywhere. An IDE is just a glorified text editor. There is no header `iostream.h`, you should do `#include <iostream>`. All of the C++ library headers *do not* end in `.h`. However, the C library headers *do*. When you `#include <iostream>`, the `cout` object is in the `std` namespace - you must qualify it with `std::cout` (unless you do something like `using namespace std;` - but that is **very naughty**).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily look up the explanation for the error, by googling the error code. E.g. googling for 'C4430' would lead you [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173696). The reason is, as others have stated, that you haven't declared the return type for `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you need the extra `int` in the typedef, I thought from memory unsigned short (by default) is an int.

Comment: removed the int in the typedef defintion, still getting the same error

Comment: I removed the int and compiled it on my MaC works fine. I've also added a return type to main.