# Including PortableDevice.h causes a lot of errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, wpd

I read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/dd319341(v=vs.85).aspx) and just created a cpp console project in VisualStudio 2017 including some headers.

stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <PortableDeviceApi.h>
#include <PortableDevice.h>
```

All I've done is this and I got a lots of errors.

```
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2143   구문 오류: ','이(가) '&' 앞에 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2803   'operator =='에는 클래스 형식의 정식 매개 변수가 적어도 하나는 있어야 합니다.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2805   이항 'operator =='에 매개 변수가 너무 적습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2065   'pkeyOne': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2228   '.pid' 왼쪽에는 클래스/구조체/공용 구조체가 있어야 합니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2065   'pkeyOther': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C2228   '.fmtid' 왼쪽에는 클래스/구조체/공용 구조체가 있어야 합니다.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C3861   'IsEqualIID': 식별자를 찾을 수 없습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 35  
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2143   구문 오류: ','이(가) '&' 앞에 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2803   'operator !='에는 클래스 형식의 정식 매개 변수가 적어도 하나는 있어야 합니다.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2805   이항 'operator !='에 매개 변수가 너무 적습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2065   'pkeyOne': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.  ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2065   'pkeyOther': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\propkeydef.h 36  
오류  C2065   'GUID_DEVINTERFACE_WPD': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 18  
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 18  
오류  C2440   '초기화 중': 'initializer list'에서 'int'(으)로 변환할 수 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 18  
오류  C2065   'GUID_DEVINTERFACE_WPD_PRIVATE': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 23  
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 23  
오류  C2374   'DEFINE_GUID': 재정의. 여러 번 초기화했습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 23  
오류  C2440   '초기화 중': 'initializer list'에서 'int'(으)로 변환할 수 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 23  
오류  C2065   'GUID_DEVINTERFACE_WPD_SERVICE': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.    ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 28  
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 28  
오류  C2374   'DEFINE_GUID': 재정의. 여러 번 초기화했습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 28  
오류  C2440   '초기화 중': 'initializer list'에서 'int'(으)로 변환할 수 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 28  
오류  C2065   'WPD_EVENT_NOTIFICATION': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 404 
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 404 
오류  C2374   'DEFINE_GUID': 재정의. 여러 번 초기화했습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 404 
오류  C2440   '초기화 중': 'initializer list'에서 'int'(으)로 변환할 수 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 404 
오류  C2065   'WPD_EVENT_OBJECT_ADDED': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 408 
오류  C4430   형식 지정자가 없습니다. int로 가정합니다. 참고: C++에서는 기본 int를 지원하지 않습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 408 
오류  C2374   'DEFINE_GUID': 재정의. 여러 번 초기화했습니다.   ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 408 
오류  C2440   '초기화 중': 'initializer list'에서 'int'(으)로 변환할 수 없습니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 408 
오류  C2065   'WPD_EVENT_OBJECT_REMOVED': 선언되지 않은 식별자입니다. ConsoleApplication1 c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\portabledevice.h 412 
...
```

I have no idea to handle this since I am not familiar with Windows development and this is first time to create an Windows app. How can I solve this problem or how can I get an information about this?

Comment: It complains about C++ specific declarations.  The compiler somehow thinks it is compiling a .c file but still has the `__cplusplus` macro defined.  Don't define it yourself, I guess.  Be sure to use a project template to get started, don't wildly make changes without telling anybody about it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I left the initial answer, but I think it's irrelevant. Are you positive that you included files in the following order as in your question?

```
#include <PortableDeviceApi.h>
#include <PortableDevice.h>
```

As this doesn't produce any errors in the empty console app, however, should you reverse the order as below, the list of errors matches your question:

```
#include <PortableDevice.h>
#include <PortableDeviceApi.h>
```

All above assuming you have SDK installed.

Initial answer (most likely irrelevant to the problem)
This is just a guess since your question is incomplete (as it doesn't have full code to reproduce the problem), but I think you might have forgotten to add [proper `main` returning `int` which could result in C4430](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15186416/c-compiler-error-c4430-c-doesnt-support-default-int) to your console application or some other simple error as next one in your error list [C2143](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697190/error-c2143-syntax-error-missing-before-type). Some missing `;` after a statement or `int` in definition or declaration.

Perform binary search in your source code by commenting parts of it to see what exactly causes the errors and if you can't find it yourself in a small code snippet, post your source code in your question.

Comment: I just created empty console app project and add two code. "#include <PortableDevice.h>" and "#include <PortableDeviceApi.h>". This two code cause error.

Comment: @RedLaboratory, does it make a difference if you move those 2 lines of code from stdafx.h into your console app's app_name.cpp (or wherever your main() is)? Does it produce same errors or different ones?